# Identify Custom Class in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am making a library,
In one of the functionality, I receive an object and I have to perform an operation on fields and save them on a Map.
The object can have a field of type custom class which will again have fields and in that case, I'll need a nested hashmap. To do that I'll need to call my function recursively if the type of field in a custom class.

Now the problem is, how will I check if the type of field is a custom class or not, right now I am doing it by package name but have to make it general

```
 private fun getAllFields(`object`: Any): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val map: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

    val internalMap: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    for (field in `object`::class.java.declaredFields.toMutableList()) {
        field.isAccessible = true
        if (field.type.name.contains("com.example")) {
            internalMap.putAll(getAllFields(field.get(`object`)))
        }
```

Comment: Is this by any chance an xy problem? https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using reflection, you could introduce an annotation:

```kotlin
package org.your.library

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class YourCoolAnnotation
```

Which then can be used by the users of your library to annotate the classes that they want to be nested:

```kotlin
package com.example.libraryuser

@YourCoolAnnotation
class MyCustomClass
```

Then you can replace your:

```kotlin
if (field.type.name.contains("com.example")) {
```

With:

```kotlin
if (field.type.isAnnotationPresent(YourCoolAnnotation::class.java)) {
```

---

You could also specify the annotation to be only used on fields which would make this a lot more dynamic:

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class YourCoolAnnotation
```

and then check if the field has the annotation and not the type itself:

```kotlin
if (field.isAnnotationPresent(YourCoolAnnotation::class.java)) {
```

Comment: great Idea, I'll look around